# Replace numbers with array

Tags: php, arrays

how to put integer values, taken by another array, instead of 1,2,3 like this?

```
$arr_id = array(1,2,3); //this arr_id go to line 2 instead of 1,2,3
'id' => array('$in' => array(1,2,3))
```

---

well, putting $arr_id instead of "1,2,3"... something like this

```
'id' => array('$in' => array($arr_id))
```

---

the problem is that 1,2,3 are number, but in my $arr_id i've strings. If i try to convert string to int i've a problem with "," too

here

```
array($arr_id))
```

i need to have integers (not string) taken by $arr_id, separated by ","...

Comment: It looks like they're already integers. Are you saying that `$arr_id` is actually equal to the string "1,2,3"? Can you clarify with code examples exactly what you're starting with and what you want to end up with?

Comment: Or is it already an array of ints and you're trying to _turn it into_ "1,2,3"?

Comment: @Don'tPanic i'm tryin' to put it inside 1,2,3 in the line 'id' => array('$in' => array(1,2,3)). It starts with a string (verified by echo gettype($arr_id);) . Please read below in the first answer and relative comments... there's a progression :)

Comment: if i wrote
'id' => array('$in' => array($array_replaced[1])) or
'id' => array('$in' => array($array_replaced[2]))

the code works fine. But i can't write [integers. Very strange problem....

Comment: I'd really like to help. But I don't really understand from your description what you're starting with or what you want to end up with. Can you edit your question to add a code example that shows that?

Comment: @Don'tPanic tnx. Ok. **1)** start with a string `$arr_id = "1,2,3"` **2)** string changed in an array `$new_array = explode("," , $arr_id);` **3)** used a function wrote below `$array_replaced = array_map('intval',$new_array);` **4)** replace 1,2,3 in `id' => array('$in' => array($array_replaced))` doensn't work **5)** if i write `id' => array('$in' => array($array_replaced[1]))` the code works (all variables and arrays are ok)

Comment: i need to pass to the $in function (MongoDB) a list of array[]... but in every database the id field is an integer (in mysql and others too... there's the same function $in). So i need to pass this group of IDs as a numeric parameter (a list of integers). I think it's impossible to write this with array[] 'cause you MUST to write the array index for the query. By shell it's very easy... by php should be "impossible"...

Answer (score 1):

You can convert a string array to an int array in PHP using:

```
$arr_id_str = array("1","2","3");
var_dump(array_map('intval',$arr_id_str));
```

Comment: ok... your code is correct but... there's a problem: if i put $array_replaced

$array_replaced = array_map('intval',$arr_id_str);

inside 

'id' => array('$in' => array($array_replaced))

the code doesn't work 

Warning: array_values() expects parameter 1 to be array, null given

i can't write $array_replaced[1] or 2 or 3... 'cause is the same to write 1,2,3. This fields is dynamic.....